# Parse yaml files with "---" in it

Tags: go, yaml

I'm using https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml to parse yaml files:

```
type TestConfig struct {
   Test string `yaml:"test"`
}
```

yaml file:

```
test: 123

---

test: 456
```

But yaml.Unmarshal() only parses the first segment, how can I parse the rest of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But yaml.Unmarshal() only parses the first segment, how can I parse the rest of it?

[`yaml.Unmarshal`'s doc](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Unmarshal) says (emphasis mine):

> Unmarshal decodes *the first document* found within the in byte slice and assigns decoded values into the out value.

If you want to decode a *series* of documents, call `yaml.NewDecoder()` on  a stream of your data and then call your decoder's `.Decode(...)` multiple times.  Use `io.EOF` to identify the end of records.

I usually use an infinite `for` loop with a `break` condition for this:

```
decoder := yaml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(data))
for {
    var d Doc
    if err := decoder.Decode(&d); err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Document decode failed: %w", err))
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", d)
}
fmt.Printf("All documents decoded")
```

(https://go.dev/play/p/01xdzDN0qB7)